# How to use Openstreet iOS

Tags: ios, openstreetmap

I have to use open street map in Objective C to show a shortest route from current location, it would be helpful if anybody could help me with this as very less info is available on this

Comment: Did you already take a look at https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing and https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Apple_iOS? It mentions various online services for routing as well as libraries for iOS.

Comment: I want to make use of it in India, MKMapview MKDirection not available for india ...and don't want to use Google Map . Is there third party API which charge nominal or free

Comment: Take a look at the online services mentioned in the first link. Many of these online routers can be installed locally without any fee.